# angulardart: pass event to another compoment

Tags: angular, dart, angular-dart

I have two components componentA and componentB. Both of them are siblings, and are children of componentMother.

When componentA clicked, a click event is triggered and processed by event handlerA. **How to pass this event to componentB and processed by event handler B?**

Any comments welcomed. Some pieces of codes are welcomed. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

At the risk of sounding a bit sketchy, you have to go through your mother. Siblings can't directly speak to each other.

If I understand you correctly, your mother.component.html looks somewhat like this:

```
<comp-a (your-event)="handleEvent()"></comp-a>
<comp-b></comp-b>
```

The `handleEvent()` supplied there is a method that should exist on your `MotherComponent`, because events (`EventEmitter`) in Angular are always communicated upwards to their parent.

In `MotherComponent` you can then pass the event along to the `CompBComponent`:

```
export class MotherComponent {
    @ViewChild(CompBComponent)
    compB: CompBComponent;

    handleEvent() {
        this.compB.doStuff();
    }
}
```

This is fine for this relatively simple scenario. If you have to go up multiple layers and then always go down multiple layers, this solution quickly becomes tiresome. Creating an injectable service with some sort of `observable` property will then probably become a better fit.

p.s. I'm not all that fluent in Dart, so hopefully TypeScript examples will make sense for you.

Answer (score 1):

use `EventEmitter` to send the event to to the `motherComponent`.. 
see: https://angular.io/api/core/EventEmitter

Answer (score 0):

Passing the event through the parent is the best practice, but there is another way. You can couple the components using a var ref.

```
<compA #a ></compA><compB [clickStream]="a.click"></compB>

class CompA {
  StreamController _onClick = new StreamController();
  @Output()
  Stream click = _onClick.stream;
}

class CompB {
  @Input()
  set clickStream(Stream stream) {
    stream.listen(() {
      // Do work here on click
    });
  }
}
```

Again this isn't quite best practice but is should work.